# Why don't lightsaber users turn off their lightsaber midfight to pass through their enemy's defense?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Theoretically if two lightsabers clashed, couldn't one of them quickly switch off and on to "phase" through the other lightsaber and insta-kill the opponent?

Comment: Sure they could but then the opponents lightsaber would also phase through and most likely insta kill you.

Comment: The user initiating the phase would have a greater chance of avoiding their opponent and could sidestep, while the opponent would be surprised.Obviously the way the lightsabers would be angled after a clash would make a difference, the user switching off would have to make sure that the enemy's lightsaber would pass through thin air, while their's would hit the enemy.

Comment: It takes a little time for lightsabers to expand and retract - about half a second to expand and a full second to retract, judging from movie clips (though there is some inconsistency). That is a long time in a lightsaber duel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ey3g6BmuTI

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen exactly this - that opening might not be a huge amount of time, but considering Force users are able to use their lightsabers to deflect blaster shots, an opening of a second or more where your opponent is fully defenceless is a huge advantage. The person dropping their defence would have to be absolutely sure the gambit would pay off (or very desperate).

Comment: Do we know if it's possible to re-engage a lightsaber before it has fully shut off?  (I don't know the canon well enough.)  If not, then Klaus's point is very significant here.  If the Jedi needs to wait for the saber to fully shut off before he can turn it on again that means waiting the *full second and a half* before his weapon is rearmed.  If nothing else, that would ruin the strike he *was in the middle of making* and render this technique worthless.  Sure he could avoid the opponent's parry, but his own weapon would not be extended again in time to complete the blow.

Comment: I forgot how long it took to actually turn lightsabers on and off, those are good points. I guess the only way for this to be a viable strategy would be to design a new type of lightsaber that can instantly switch on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that kind of obvious? Most likely, they will get *instakilled* via the same action by their opponent as both sabres will be able to reach their destination.

Comment: But as the user initiating the switch off, they can try to avoid the opponent, while the opponent will be caught by surprise. Sure its a risky manoeuvre, but I don't see why this kind of surprise attack is never used.

Comment: I guess most of Jedi and Sith are rather experienced fighters not to be so easily caught by this. Also, the one switching off loses some time due to this action which can be taken advantage of by their opponent. Overall, it's a trade-off between getting surprise factor while being defenceless or just not doing it. In general, fighters need to catch the an opponent on a surprise factor when the opponent is of greater strength or at least equal, which makes such a move of not so worthy to risk it all